# amp-consent no more working on amp-ad and amp-embeded elements

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Without any noteworthy changes the amp-consent element does not work on our amp-ad and amp-embeded elements.

Page is valide, the attribute data-block-on-consent is available, but for some reasons the content within the amp-ad and amp-embeded gets loaded and the desired effect of disabling the ad shows no reaction.

For simple testing I just added amp-img and it behaves in expected manner on user consent.

some simple test with following element:

```
   <amp-ad data-block-on-consent
            width="300"
            height="250"
            type="a9"
            data-aax_size="300x250"
            data-aax_pubname="test123"
            data-aax_src="302">
    </amp-ad>
```

results in:

```
Error: Unknown attribute for a9: blockOnConsent.
```

What I am actually doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad#attributes), the attributes for `amp-ad` / `amp-embed` are the following, `type` (required), `src`(optional), `data-foo-bar`, `data-vars-foo-bar`, `json` (optional), `data-consent-notification-id` (optional), `data-loading-strategy` (optional), `common attributes`. From your code, I am not sure if `data-block-on-consent` must be there. For [`amp-consent`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-consent)  try to refer in the link.

Comment: the "data-block-on-consent" attribute is not amp-ad specific, it works on all amp elements except the amp-consent. It worked so far well but for some reasons not more.

Comment: This issue has been already fixed by the AMP-Developers.